# NdsManager Android error

Tags: android

I am facing a problem here, until version 6.0 works fine now from 6.0 onwards it does not work what I do not understand is that it was permission, but the error is as if the listener was already in use by NsdManager.
Has anyone ever had this same mistake? Thank you very much in advance.............

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener already in useat android.net.nsd.NsdManager.registerService(NsdManager.java:485)
          at br.com.shootinghouse.sc.ServerActivity.registerService(ServerActivity.java:76)
          at br.com.shootinghouse.sc.ServerActivity.onResume(ServerActivity.java:50)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
          at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6783)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

code

```
public class ServerActivity extends MonitorarSerChamadoActivity {
private Manager manager;
private LiteListener listener;
private String SERVICE_NAME = "Server device";
private String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.";
private int SERVICE_Port = 5432;
private NsdManager mNsdManager;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NSD_SERVICE);
    registerService(SERVICE_Port);
    try {
        manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startListener();
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://" + getLocalIpAddress() + ":" + SERVICE_Port + "/banco144");
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Listening on :: " + url.toString() + " "
            + SERVICE_NAME + " " +
            SERVICE_TYPE);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mNsdManager != null) {
        registerService(SERVICE_Port);
    }

}
void startListener() {
    listener = new LiteListener(manager, SERVICE_Port, null);
    Thread thread = new Thread(listener);
    thread.start();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mNsdManager != null) {
        mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
public void registerService(int port) {
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setServiceName(SERVICE_NAME);
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);
    try {
        mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo NsdServiceInfo) {
        SERVICE_NAME = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
    }
};
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    return Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change

```
mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo nsdServiceInfo) {

        }
    });
```

> NsdManager.ResolveListener: to receive callback upon success or failure. Cannot be null. Cannot be in use for an active service resolution.

i.e do not pass a listener that has already been registered.

Comment: Just one more question. I need to call the unregisterService (mRegistrationListener) method in onDestroy? or do not need